# Displaying cells in 2D for a maze game service

Tags: javascript, css, html, graphics

I am creating Web API for a 2D maze game.  I have a  service with two Get methods – one for retrieving all cells and one for retrieving specific cell details( with next possible move links).

The cells list will be retrieved in the following format for the request http://localhost:51910/api/cells.

```
<Cell>
  <BottomIsWall>true</BottomIsWall>
  <IsExtCell>false</IsExtCell>
  <IsStartCell>false</IsStartCell>
  <LeftIsWall>true</LeftIsWall>
  <RelativeName>Self</RelativeName>
  <RightIsWall>false</RightIsWall>
  <TopIsWall>false</TopIsWall>
  <XVal>0</XVal>
  <YVal>0</YVal>
</Cell>
<Cell>
  <BottomIsWall>false</BottomIsWall>
  <IsExtCell>false</IsExtCell>
  <IsStartCell>true</IsStartCell>
  <LeftIsWall>false</LeftIsWall>
  <RelativeName>Self</RelativeName>
  <RightIsWall>false</RightIsWall>
  <TopIsWall>true</TopIsWall>
  <XVal>1</XVal>
  <YVal>0</YVal>
</Cell>
```

Response for the specific cell request will be as follows (for the request http://localhost:51910/api/cells/21, when accept header `application/hal+xml` is used). The links (up, right, down and left) will be added if navigation is allowed in that direction.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resource rel="self" href="~/api/cells/21">
    <link rel="down" href="~/api/cells/20" />
    <link rel="left" href="~/api/cells/11" />
    <link rel="up" href="~/api/cells/22" />
</resource>
```

User can click on the available links to navigate to the next cell. At each response, I need to display all the cells in a `2D` Cartesian diagram, with users current position. I googled for code which will helps to display the cells (with door/ wall) – but I couldn’t find one.

I found many tutorials which has code and algorithm for generating maze. I don’t have to generate maze. I have maze already defined and available. I need to just plot it for the user to see it.

What is the simplest approach for achieving this display?

[image]

Note:  I need to apply the css styles using javascript, based on the cells returned by the service. It can be any 4X4 maze.

Comment: Do you want to use images and a spritemap, or just html elements?

Comment: @JonSG Both are acceptable

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit crappy, but that has more to do with the un-optimized choice ad-hoc spritemap.  You should be able to assign classes to the cells based on your data.  The containing structure could just as easily be div based of course.

**UPDATE:**
I have updated this answer to be driven off the data provided.

There are lots of ways to optimize this, this is just something quick and dirty to give you a way to move forward.

For example, given your data structure, it might be just as easy to use xpath than to convert the xml to JSON.  Also, one might z-index door images on top of the room walls rather than picking out one of 16 rooms as I have done.

```js
// --------------------------------
// Maze data from service.
// --------------------------------
var xmlString = "<root><Cell><BottomIsWall>true</BottomIsWall><IsExtCell>false</IsExtCell><IsStartCell>false</IsStartCell><LeftIsWall>true</LeftIsWall><RelativeName>Self</RelativeName><RightIsWall>false</RightIsWall><TopIsWall>false</TopIsWall><XVal>0</XVal><YVal>0</YVal></Cell><Cell><BottomIsWall>false</BottomIsWall><IsExtCell>false</IsExtCell><IsStartCell>true</IsStartCell><LeftIsWall>false</LeftIsWall><RelativeName>Self</RelativeName><RightIsWall>false</RightIsWall><TopIsWall>true</TopIsWall><XVal>1</XVal><YVal>0</YVal></Cell></root>";
// --------------------------------

// --------------------------------
// Convert the XML text to JSON
// --------------------------------
var data = (function(xmlString){
    // --------------------------------
    // Changes XML to JSON
    // see: https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json
    // --------------------------------
    function xmlToJson(xml) {
        // Create the return object
        var obj = {};

        if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
            // do attributes
            if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
            obj["@attributes"] = {};
                for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                    var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                    obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
                }
            }
        } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
            obj = xml.nodeValue;
        }

        // do children
        if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
            for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
                var nodeName = item.nodeName;
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                    obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
                } else {
                    if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                        var old = obj[nodeName];
                        obj[nodeName] = [];
                        obj[nodeName].push(old);
                    }
                    obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    };
    // --------------------------------
  
    var _parser = new window.DOMParser();
    var xmlData = _parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

    return xmlToJson(xmlData);
})(xmlString);
// --------------------------------

// --------------------------------
// For each TD in the maze, find the service data and
// set the room look.
// --------------------------------
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).forEach(function(row, rowIndex){
  Array.from(row.querySelectorAll("td")).forEach(function(col, colIndex){

    // ---------------------
    // Find the data element for this cell
    // ---------------------
    var cellData = data.root.Cell.filter(function(data){
      var isRowMatch = data.YVal["#text"] == (3 - rowIndex);
      var isColMatch = data.XVal["#text"] == colIndex;
      return (isRowMatch && isColMatch);
    });
    // ---------------------
    
    var cellType = "cell-00";
    var cellRotation = "cell-south";

    // ---------------------
    // if there is some issue with the data set the cell to the void
    // ---------------------
    if(cellData.length !== 1) {
      col.classList.add(cellType);
      col.classList.add(cellRotation);
      return;
    }
    // ---------------------
    
    // ---------------------
    // Where are the doors?
    // ---------------------
    var isDoor_North = cellData[0].TopIsWall["#text"] === "false";
    var isDoor_East = cellData[0].RightIsWall["#text"] === "false";
    var isDoor_South = cellData[0].BottomIsWall["#text"] === "false";
    var isDoor_West = cellData[0].LeftIsWall["#text"] === "false";
    // ---------------------

    // ---------------------
    // Determine the classes based on where the doors are
    // ---------------------
    switch(true) {
        case (isDoor_North && isDoor_East && isDoor_South && isDoor_West):
          break;
        case (isDoor_North && isDoor_East && isDoor_South && !isDoor_West):
          break;
        case (isDoor_North && isDoor_East && !isDoor_South && isDoor_West):
          break;
        case (isDoor_North && isDoor_East && !isDoor_South && !isDoor_West):
          cellType = "cell-03";
          cellRotation = "cell-west";
          break;
        case (isDoor_North && !isDoor_East && isDoor_South && isDoor_West):
          break;
        case (isDoor_North && !isDoor_East && isDoor_South && !isDoor_West):
          break;
        case (isDoor_North && !isDoor_East && !isDoor_South && isDoor_West):
          break;
        case (isDoor_North && !isDoor_East && !isDoor_South && !isDoor_West):
          break;
        case (!isDoor_North && isDoor_East && isDoor_South && isDoor_West):
          cellType = "cell-04";
          cellRotation = "cell-east";
          break;
        case (!isDoor_North && isDoor_East && isDoor_South && !isDoor_West):
          break;
        case (!isDoor_North && isDoor_East && !isDoor_South && isDoor_West):
          break;
        case (!isDoor_North && isDoor_East && !isDoor_South && !isDoor_West):
          break;
        case (!isDoor_North && !isDoor_East && isDoor_South && isDoor_West):
          break;
        case (!isDoor_North && !isDoor_East && isDoor_South && !isDoor_West):
          break;
        case (!isDoor_North && !isDoor_East && !isDoor_South && isDoor_West):
          break;
        case (!isDoor_North && !isDoor_East && !isDoor_South && !isDoor_West):
          break;
    }
    // ---------------------

    // ---------------------
    // Assign the proper classes based on our data.
    // ---------------------
    col.classList.add(cellType);
    col.classList.add(cellRotation);
    // ---------------------

  });
});
// ---------------------
```

```css
.cell {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v323/ShadowDragon8685/KestralDefiant_zps88896fb8.png);
}

.cell-00 { background-position: -0px -15px; }
.cell-01 { background-position: -115px -138px; }
.cell-02 { background-position: -44px -173px; }
.cell-03 { background-position: -254px -103px; }
.cell-04 { background-position: -254px -278px; }

.cell-north { transform: rotate(180deg); }
.cell-east { transform: rotate(90deg); }
.cell-south { transform: rotate(0deg); }
.cell-west { transform: rotate(270deg); }
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <tr><td class="cell"></td><td class="cell"></td><td class="cell"></td><td class="cell"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="cell"></td><td class="cell"></td><td class="cell"></td><td class="cell"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="cell"></td><td class="cell"></td><td class="cell"></td><td class="cell"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="cell"></td><td class="cell"></td><td class="cell"></td><td class="cell"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is promising - thanks!!!. If you can elaborate the logic, it will help me understand it better. Also, I need to apply the css styles using javascript, based on the cells returned by the service. It can be any 4X4 maze. Do you have a sample Javascript for this?